# Javascript Eval to work for both function and plain string

Tags: javascript, eval

I want to display a list of items, now sometimes these items' title will just be a plain string, and sometimes it might be a value returned by a function.

How can I make both events work using eval() ?

Here is an example code:

```
var a1 = "formatDate('" + startTime + "') + ' - ' + formatDate('" + endTime + "')"
var a2 = "#america"

var result1 = eval(a1) // works well!
var result2 = eval(a2) // doesn't work, need to use eval('a2') but then first one doesn't work
```

Only thing I can think of is when creating the string for example "#america" have it saved like "'#america'" instead, but I would rather avoid it

[edit]

Eventually I will have something like this:

```
arr.push("formatDate('" + startTime + "') + ' - ' + formatDate('" + endTime + "')");
arr.push("#america");
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var ev = eval(arr[i]);
    console.log(ev);
}
```

Comment: Why `eval`, you can directly call the function

Comment: `"#america'` should be `"#america"`;

Comment: Another thing, if your `a2`s gonna be a string, why do you need to `eval()` it?

Comment: @AdityaParab correct, thanks for the edit

Comment: I will ultimately have an array of values, I want to iterate on them and get their value, while the value might be just a plain string, or an expression I need to evaluate first. I don't know when it might be a string and when an expression

Comment: How do you even eval on a string like that? How does `eval("#america");` work?

Comment: Sorry, might not have been clear, check my edit, I've added the iteration that clear things up

Comment: What. When you do `eval()` it runs the calculation/function/Javascript code. "#america" is not Javascript code, so `eval("#america")` is doing absolutely nothing. What exactly do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: My end goal is displaying a text, sometimes its just a plain string and sometimes its an expression that needs evaluation. I don't NEED to run eval on a string, but how can I avoid it when I don't know what I currently got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is wrapping the eval in a try catch block, if the eval succeeds then return the value otherwise return the value originally passed to function. There are many cases where eval can fail as it is simply trying to parse the string as valid JavaScript so any invalid JS not just a simple string can cause it to fail so its better to be safe and catch any error that comes out of it.

```
var evaluate = function(value) {
    try {
        return eval(value);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't solve what he's asking. Post this in a comment.

Comment: How doesn't it solve what he is asking? all he does with the evaluated code is log it to the console which in this case will work perfectly

Comment: I'll have to side with gabriel here; it's not pretty, but it does address the issue at hand. Depending on which circumstances OP has control over, it may well be the *only* way to solve the issue.

Comment: Right, I get what you mean now, gabriel. I've removed the downvote, but I certainly don't think wrapping it in a try catch statement is the way to go.

Comment: Ideally he wouldn't be using eval at all but as David said if he doesn't have control over the input there really is no other way.

Comment: I can see that. I misunderstood the whole point of this because of his `eval("#america")` part. My bad :)

Answer (score 1):

`var ev = eval(a2)` would be equivalent to `var ev = eval('#america')` which doesn't make any real sense.

When you say `eval('a2')` works, I assume that `ev = '#america'` is the desired outcome. The `'a2'` expression is evaluated as simply accessing the value of the variable of that name.

You're basically just having a series of strings that may be valid javascript code, or may not, and there's no way to tell which is which. In that case, the best you can do is something like

```
try { 
  ev = eval(arr[i]);
} catch(ex) {
  ev = arr[i];
}
```

... which obviously looks terrible. Can you control the content of the entries in `arr`?

```
arr.push(function() { 
   return formatDate(startTime) - formatDate(endTime);
});
arr.push("#america");
```

In that case, you could check for the type of each entry, and act on it accordingly:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var ev = typeof arr[i] == 'function' ? arr[i]() : arr[i];
  console.log(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is that i should do:

```
var a1 = function(){ 
            return formatDate(startTime) + formatDate(endTime) 
         }
var a2 = "#america"
var result1 = a1();
var result2 = a2;
```

Yo can check with typeof(a1) if the var is a function or an object or anyting else.

```
if(typeof(a1)=='function'){
   result = a1();
}else{
   result=a1;
}
```